# Return frequency of string in MYSQL column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

after searching for several questions, i'm still struggling with mysql queries in PHP, my current goal is to do a MYSQL query that counts how many repeated strings are in a column and then return this amount in a INT variable to be written in the database.
The current code looks like:

```
//Fetch value from form and uppercase the string
$glitter = utf8_decode(strtoupper($_POST['code_string'])); 

$magic = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE CODE_STR = '$glitter'");
```

The next step is inserting the var $magic into a INT field in the database, however the value is always 0.
Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: could you please check the $glitter is this returning correct value?

Comment: Your first problem is you're using the **mysql_** function, which is depreciated. You should look at MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @Styphon Thanks for the advice, i'll look for using MySQLi for now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
try this

```
$magic = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE CODE_STR = '$glitter'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($magic);
$count = $row['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. What you need to do now is

Change your query from

```
$magic = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE CODE_STR = '$glitter'");
```

to

```
$magic = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total_num FROM table WHERE CODE_STR = '$glitter'");
```

**mysql_fetch_assoc()** Use the returned value from table

```
$magic_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($magic);
echo $magic_row['total_num'];
```

See

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php